# Why does this regexec() in C return as a match, when it shouldn't?

Tags: c, regex

```
regex_t reg;
int value;
int return_value;
value = regcomp(&reg, "^[2-9]+#*", REG_EXTENDED);
if (value == 0){
    return_value = regexec(&reg, nums, 0, NULL, 0);
}
```

When I pass in nums = "2 23", with that space in the middle, the regexec returns a 0, or a match. Confused as to how to correct the regex or the C code itself to fix this.

I want the regex to be that so that only digits 2-9 are accepted, followed by any number of pound signs. No other symbols, or no pound signs at the beginning.

Comment: You should anchor your regex with `$` too: `^[2-9]+#*$`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin ah, that worked. What does the $ anchor do in this case?

Comment: It is opposite of `^`. It matches the end of string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @M.NejatAydin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is matching the digit 2, followed by zero pound signs, at the beginning of the subject string. You can see this for yourself by supplying one `regmatch_t` object to regexec via its third and fourth arguments; the values written to this object will indicate that the regex matched only the first character of the string.

If you want to match only when the *entire string* matches, add a `$` to the end of your regex. This changes the meaning of the regex to "match the beginning of the string, followed by one or more digits 2-9, followed by zero or more pound signs, *followed by the end of the string*."